# Attempt at invoking a parallel task using Redux-Saga yield all() not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to run two tasks in parallel using yield all() but getting the following log error `Object(...) is not a function`

When I invoke `const response = yield call(request, url)` on its own it works. Not sure why yield all() doesn't like the request function I'm passing in.

Here is the code,

```
const url = `${apiHost}${getSpecificTestConfiguration.endpoint}${configurationId}`;


    const [response, itemPool] = yield all([
      call(request, url),
      put(getItemPool(itemPoolId)),
    ]);
```

and here is the request function passed into the call effect where the error is thrown

```
/**
 * Requests a URL, returning a promise
 *
 * @param  {string} url       The URL we want to request
 * @param  {object} [options] The options we want to pass to "fetch"
 * @return {object}           An object containing either "data" or "err"
 */
export default function request(url, options = {}) {
  const opts = addHeaders(options);

  return fetch(url, opts)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then((data) => ({ data }));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I can't test this right now, but perhaps `all` doesn't take non-blocking effects?  I don't see a reason you'd need to have `put` within an `all` seeing as `put` is non-blocking.  Perhaps try pulling it out to before the `all` or using `putResolve` if you're expecting a `Promise` back.

Answer (score 1):

My earlier comment was definitely off-base.

Make sure your version of `redux-saga` is `0.15.0` or higher.  This is when `all` was added.

I was able to reproduce your exact issue in my project using version `0.14.X` and the following import: `import { ..., all } from 'redux-saga/es/effects`, which very helpfully does NOT complain that `all` doesn't exist.  Issue was solved by updating to `^0.15.0` and importing from `'redux-saga/effects'`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was definitely the problem. I should have though of that. I appreciate the assist!